# Recommended way to update config values in an automated way?

Tags: linux, automation

To give some context, I have a build server task that requires updating a configuration file (in yaml format) field value and pushing to a repo to be used later.My immediate thought was to use some form of regex search/replace but I'm wondering if there are other/better ways to accomplish this?

i.e:

```
# Before
my_field : 2

# After
my_field : 3.1
```

Ofcourse the file will contain other fields with values that need to be untouched.

**EDIT**

So as per rbtux's suggestion I found a ruby yaml modules which solves my problem. Here's how it works:

source.yaml:

```
---
some_value: 1
my_value: 2
new_value: 3
```

replace.ruby:

```
require 'yaml'

hiera = YAML.load_file('source.yaml');

hiera['my_value'] = "other data"

File.open('source.yaml','r+') do |h| 
   h.write hiera.to_yaml
end

puts hiera['my_value'] # outputs my_value as 'other data' with other variables intact
```

You can extend this to pass the value as an argument.

Comment: Windows? Linux? Mac? BSD? Details, or you will always be aspiring.

Comment: Haha. Linux, updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way would be to choose a script language perl, python, ruby, etc. that provides yaml manipulation utilities.

if the file is simple enough, you could get away with a sed hack though:

```
sed 's/^\(\s*my_field\s*:\s*\).*/\1new-value/'
```

Comment: Good point about scripting language providing yaml manipulation utilities. Didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: you can use `sed -r` to avoid the parenthesis escape, and just use regular `(` and `)`

Comment: Great hack, works with any simple YAML file and agree with Noam, can use -r and also -ibak to replace (with backup of oldFile)

sed -ibak -r -e 's/^\(\s*my_field\s*:\s*\).*/\1new-value/'